# Tensorflow.python module not found how to resolve this error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

so I am running my tensorflow script I wrote based on the docs but it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r0bin\Downloads\dads\Niggass.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\r0bin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>

    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'
```

which is kinda weird and I tried uninstalling and installing again but nothing worked.

I tried making an ai based on a model in python using tensorflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of tensorflow? I am using 2.13 and I dont have this pb

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a venv and install all your dependencies there.

Then run your code in that.

Virtual Environment:  (Isolate your project dependencies i.e the packages and their versions required for that project)

Note : The .py file does not need to be placed in the venv folder.
Create the venv , activate it and then use it to run your code.

Also, from your error message it looks like you are using Tensorflow in Windows.

You need to know that 2.10 version onwards, Tensorflow does not have support for Windows native.

You need to run it on WSL.

Please refer to this docs [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to get through with it.